Do function in $u\in C^{1}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap \dot{H}^1$ satisfy the following decay estimate?
Let $u\in C^{1}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap \dot{H}^1$ be a smooth compactly supported function. Then is the following decay estimate correct?
\begin{align}
|u|(r,\theta) &\leq \int_r^\infty |\partial_{\tau} u|(\tau, \theta) d\tau\\
&\leq \left(\int_r^\infty |\partial_{\tau} u|^2(\tau, \theta) \tau^{n-1}d\tau \right)^{1/2}\left(\int_r^\infty  \tau^{-n+1} d\tau \right)^{1/2} \\
&\leq \frac{\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus B_r)}}{r^{\frac{n-2}{2}}}\\
\end{align}
Here $r=|x|$ denotes the radial component in the above estimate.

What if $supp \ u \subset B_r$? Then rhs is zero, lhs not.

@daw then $u=0$ when $|x|=r$ in which case both sides of the estimate are zero

The first inequality is an application of the FTC, and the second is Cauchy-Schwarz applied to the functions $\partial_\tau u$ and $\tau^{(1-n)/2}$. Can you see how to get to the third?

Yes, in the last we use that the radial gradient is controlled by the full gradient. So do you think the estimate makes sense?

I do think that this last inequality is wrong: one cannot estimate the integral along the line by the integral on the full space.

Suppose the inequality is correct.
Take an open and bounded set $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$.
Then the inequality would imply that
$$
|u(x)| \le \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\mathbb R^n)} \cdot |x|^{-\frac{n-2}2} \quad \forall x
$$
for all $u \in C_c^\infty(\Omega)$. By density, this inequality would be true for all $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$.
For $n=2$ this would imply that $H^1_0(\Omega)$ embedds into $L^\infty(\Omega)$. For $n\ge3$ and $0 \not\in \bar \Omega$ this would also imply boundedness of $H^1_0(\Omega)$-functions and the  continuity of the embedding of $H^1_0(\Omega)$ into  $L^\infty(\Omega)$. Which is a contradiction.
